# Firebase DataBase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

**Problem:** For some reason the data is not being sent to my database in firebase. Can anyone figure out why the information is not being sent?

I highlighted the code with //******** to show where I am sending it.

Rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
              ".read": "true",
              ".write": "true"

  }
}

import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
import KeychainSwift




class SignUpController: UIViewController {

    //INPUT - from keyboard email & password
    @IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!

    //Data Base Initialization
    //var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!

    let dataRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }

    //PROCESS - Checks is user has already been logged in
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

       let currentUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser

        if currentUser != nil {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "SignIn", sender: nil)
            }


    }

    func CompleteSignIn(id: String){
        let keyChain = DataService().keyChain
        keyChain.set(id , forKey: "uid")
    }


    //If SignUp button is pressed user will be directed to sign up page
    @IBAction func LoginPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "BackToLogin", sender: nil)
    }





    /*If both password and email contain text lets put them into string variables
       called email & password. Creates user and authorizes sign in                                      */

    @IBAction func SignIn(_ sender: Any){

        if let email = emailField.text, let password = passwordField.text {

            FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
                if error == nil {

                    self.CompleteSignIn(id: user!.uid) //Completese Database Sign in
                    //************************************************
                    //Send information to Database
                    let userEmail : String = self.emailField.text!
                    let userPassword : String = self.passwordField.text!
                    let userID : String = user!.uid
                    self.dataRef.child("Users").child(userID).setValue(["Email": userEmail, "Password" : userPassword])
                 //************************************************
                    print("Sign in Test")

                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SignIn", sender: nil)

                } else {
                    FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
                        if error != nil {

                            Alerts().invalidSignUpAlert(sender: self) //Alert for invalid email & Password
                            print("cant sign in user") //Programmer Debugging

                        } else {
                            self.CompleteSignIn(id: user!.uid)
                            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SignIn", sender: nil)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to see the new users in the firebase log??? Or that is also not working?

Comment: yes i am able to see users in the log

Comment: can u show the structure of database...

Comment: The database is just default nothing has ever been added

Comment: What do you mean as boolean it does not allow that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add "Users" in the rules as shown below:

```
"rules": {
  "Users":{
     ".read": "true",
     ".write": "true"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need as Boolean, not as string "true"

```
{
  "rules": {
              ".read" : true,
              ".write":true

  }
}
```

Comment: {
   "rules": {
  "Users":{
     ".read": "true",
     ".write": "true"
}
 }
}

Comment: You are welcome, but obviously mechdon did find the solution right ?

Comment: Yes. The problem was within the rules of Firebase database it self. Im still learning firebase so it was a huge help.